# How to find column values and replace in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I could do this easily in R with grepl and row indexing, but wanted to try this in shell. I have a text file that looks like what I have below. I would like to find rows where It matches `TWGX` and wherever it match, I would like to concatenate column 1 and column 2 separated by `_` and make it column values for both column 1 and column 2.

text:

```
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   1   1
TWGX-MAP    10064-8036056040    0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP    11570-8036056502    0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP    11680-8036055912    0   0   0   -9
```

This is the result I want:

```
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   1   1
TWGX-MAP_10064-8036056040   TWGX-MAP_10064-8036056040   0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP_11570-8036056502   TWGX-MAP_11570-8036056502   0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP_11680-8036055912   TWGX-MAP_11680-8036055912   0   0   0   -9
```

Comment: What's your field separator?

Comment: @Cyrus It is `\t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/TWGX/` selects the lines containing that string and applies the action that follows. The `1` is an awk shorthand that will print both the modified and unmodified lines.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} /TWGX/ {tmp = $1 "_" $2; $1 = $2 = tmp}1' file
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   2   1
NIALOAD NIALOAD 0   0   1   1
TWGX-MAP_10064-8036056040   TWGX-MAP_10064-8036056040   0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP_11570-8036056502   TWGX-MAP_11570-8036056502   0   0   0   -9
TWGX-MAP_11680-8036055912   TWGX-MAP_11680-8036055912   0   0   0   -9
```

**BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }**
# Just once, before processing the file, set FS (file separator) and OFS (output file separator) to be the tab character

**/TWGX/ {tmp = $1 "_" $2; $1 = $2 = tmp}**
# For every line that contains a match for `TWGX` create a mashup of the first two columns, and assign it to each of columns 1 and 2. (Note that in awk string concatenation is done by simply putting expressions next to one another)

**1**
# This is an awk idiom that consists of the pattern `1`, which is always true. By not explicitly specifying an action to go with that pattern, the default action of printing the whole line will be executed.